# show in a div or p what check boxes have been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to show in a div what check boxes have been checked

for example

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"><label for="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>

<p>you have selected:</p> <div>checkbox 1</div>
```

there will be more than 1 check box (37) and i need it to be able to select all the check boxes

i think that make sense

Thanks

Comment: what would you like to show??

Comment: just the label of the check box

Comment: @DanielEdwards Can you add your complete HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    $("#checked").empty();
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
        $("#checked").html($("#checked").html() + $(this).next().text() + "<br/>");
    });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0yed6asa/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function(){
   $('div').html($(':checked').map(function(){
      return $(this).next().text()
   }).get().join(','));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b5vdvhxL/)**

Comment: Nice example, but in your fiddle your forgot to change the for attribute.

Comment: @FLX: i just kept them as it is. as solution got no connection with it.